# A UIButton in my subview won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I'm Creating a custom UIView called InfoAboutBlockView, I'm adding it to my ViewController and it added correctly but when I'm pressing a button inside that custom UIView it won't fire.

I'm creating a xib file in which I design the UIView and then I create the .h and .m files

**InfoAboutBlockView.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InfoAboutBlockView : UIView

- (instancetype)init2;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@end
```

the `contentView` is the UIView linked to the .h file.

**InfoAboutBlockView.m**

```
#import "InfoAboutBlockView.h"

@implementation InfoAboutBlockView


- (instancetype)init2 {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self loadViewsFromBundle];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)loadViewsFromBundle {
    NSString *class_name = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:class_name owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
}
- (IBAction)startBlockButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    //This Won't Fire
}

@end
```

The `startBlockButtonPressed` is the button connected to the .m file.
I set a breakpoint at `startBlockButtonPressed` but it never fires.

This is how I add the custom subview to my ViewController:

```
InfoAboutBlockView *infoAboutBlockView = [[InfoAboutBlockView alloc]init2];
[self.view addSubview:infoAboutBlockView];
```

I tried bringing it to the front using `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:infoAboutBlockView];` and checked that it isn't `nil` and that the button isn't `nil` but it just won't fire.

Comment: What is your evidence that the button's target is `self` (the view controller) and that its action is `startBlockButtonPressed:`?

Comment: @matt The buttons target isn`t `self`, I'm setting the xib `File's Owner` to my `InfoAboutBlockView` Class, and then dragging to create a Touch Event.

Comment: Okay, I'm with you...

Comment: @matt is there anything else I forgot to do? shouldn't the `startBlockButtonPressed` fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the same answer I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22188740/341994

The problem is that your InfoAboutBlockView has no size. (You never gave it a frame, so its frame is zero.) Therefore it is not touchable. Therefore none of its subviews are touchable. The button is visible, and the InfoAboutBlockView's `contentView` may be visible, but they are outside the bounds of the InfoAboutBlockView, which is the size of a single point. And a subview outside its superview's bounds cannot be touched.

This would be more evident if you gave the InfoAboutBlockView a weird background color. You won't see that color when it loads.

```
InfoAboutBlockView *infoAboutBlockView = [[InfoAboutBlockView alloc]init2];
[self.view addSubview:infoAboutBlockView];
infoAboutBlockView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // you won't see the red
```

Another way to see this would be set the InfoAboutBlockView's `clipsToBounds` to YES; in that case, you wouldn't see the button.

```
InfoAboutBlockView *infoAboutBlockView = [[InfoAboutBlockView alloc]init2];
[self.view addSubview:infoAboutBlockView];
infoAboutBlockView.clipsToBounds = YES; // you won't see the button!
```

Basically that is the whole cause of the trouble; you are being fooled by the fact that when `clipsToBounds` is NO, subviews outside the bounds of a view are visible (that is what `clipsToBounds` is about). Visible, but (because of the way touch works on iOS) not touchable.

Comment: How can it has no size (the frame is zero) if it shows correctly in my `ViewController`? From my understanding if the frame is zero it just wouldn't appear.

Comment: Its subviews are visible but the view itself has no size. You are creating a UIView by saying `init`, which makes a zero-size view. You have to say `initWithFrame` and give it a size.

Comment: Is there a way to `initWithFrame` with the size i Provided in IB? Or do I always have to provide the size in code?

Comment: You didn't provide a size in IB. It doesn't come from IB. The `contentView` comes from a nib (IB). But the InfoAboutBlockView comes from saying `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: So basically I always have to provide the size of my custom view's in code? Or is there a different way?

Comment: `initWithFrame:` is the _designated initializer_ of UIView. If you create a custom UIView in code you _must_ call it. Either that or assign a `frame`. But if you do nothing at all (as here), you will have a view positioned at zero,zero and with dimensions zero,zero.