# UIButton inside UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView not responding

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay-view, cameraoverlayview

I have got a UIButton inside a UIView that I set as the cameraOverlayView.

I also scaled the uiimagepicker cameraView to cover the whole screen (as you can see below in the picture).

[image]

Here's my code :

```
 // CameraViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if(!self.imagePickerController)
        [self setupCamera];
}

-(void)setupCamera{
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView =  self.overlayView;

    [self scaleCameraPreview];

    // Present picker in the next loop (to avoid warning - "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged")
    [self performSelector:@selector(presentPicker) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void)presentPicker{
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(void)scaleCameraPreview{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    int heightOffset = 0;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        heightOffset = 120;
    }

    float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
    float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
    float scale = ceilf(((screenSize.height + heightOffset) / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;
    self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
}

-(IBAction)cameraButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [self.imagePickerController takePicture];
}
```

And this is my hierarchy of viewcontrollers:

```
- UINavigationController 
   - SWRevealViewController (manages a drawer functionality between different controllers)
     - UINavigationController (current controller for the camera)
       - CameraViewController 
         - PickerViewController (Presented modally as you can see above) 
           - PhotoTakenViewController (Controller that will fire after UIImagePicker returns an image)
```

**EDIT: Adding overlay info**

[image]

I have searched online for similar threads (e.g. [UIImagePickerController Overlay Buttons Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162857/uiimagepickercontroller-overlay-buttons-not-firing)) but didn't find any solution.

The UIButton that you can see in the picture, is inside a UIView this is the overlayView in the code assigned to the cameraOverlayView. It is also connected to the cameraButtonPressed: action through an outlet, and it works perfectly if I don't add the UIImagePickerController.

It isn't responding to any touches I don't know why.

**Does anyone know what's going on?**

Comment: try to setup(setupCamera method) in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: already tried, didn't work @zala

Comment: @jonypz tr [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btn];

Comment: Didn't work @Jageen , and did it after the imagepicker loaded

Comment: @jonypz where is the implementation of custom overlay?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman it is implemented in the storyboard (you can check it out above)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my issue but I believe in a sketchy way:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:^(void){

    // Re-add the button so it is on top of the overlay
    [self.imagePickerController.view addSubview:self.takePhotoButton];
}];
```

Will probably come back later to this issue and post an update in case I find a better solution.